# My asp.net GridView no longer displays

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Before I did the following, the `GridView` was displaying correctly, so I'll describe the changes, in case anyone has been bitten before by doing this.

I changed the `datasource` for the `GridView` from "cContact" to "cParticipant". cContact was a local class.  But cParticipant is a class in a referenced project. The referenced project is however in the solution.
Here is cParticipant:

```
<DataContract()>
Public Class cParticipant
  <DataMember()> Public Property DeptPK As Integer
  <DataMember()> Public Property DistrictCompanyName As String = ""
  <DataMember()> Public Property ParticipantID As String
  <DataMember()> Public Property Firstname As String = ""
  <DataMember()> Public Property Lastname As String = ""
  <DataMember()> Public Property BusinessEmail As String = ""
  <DataMember()> Public Property BusinessPhone As String = ""
  <DataMember()> Public Property PersonalCellPhone As String = ""
  <DataMember()> Public Property PersonalEmail As String = ""
  <DataMember()> Public Property RetainContact As Boolean = True
End Class
```

I had to do some renaming of cParticipant and its members at the same time, unfortunately. But I have searched the old names thoroughly and ensured that every instance was renamed everywhere. I have carefully checked that the new names appear in the `asp:BoundField DataField="aField"` entries in the markup.

Also, every field is mentioned in the markup, none were left out.

In the Design view of Default.aspx, the `GridView` appears, and it has 5 rows showing "Databound" in each cell.

In the F12 Developer Tools of Edge, I see the place where "rows" would appear but where the `GridView` should be, it's just `<div></div>.`

After adding a member to the list, I bind the Participants List to the `GridView`:

```
Dim C As New cParticipant
C.DeptPK=1
....
Participants.Add(C)
grdParticipantList.DataSource = Participants
grdParticipantList.DataBind()
```

"Participants" is a local Public Property in the Default.aspx.vb:

```
Public Property Participants() As List(Of cParticipant)
   Get
     Dim temp As Object = Session("Participants")
     Return If(temp Is Nothing, Nothing, _
         DirectCast(temp, List(Of cParticipant)))
   End Get

   Set(ByVal value As List(Of cParticipant))
     Session("Participants") = value
   End Set

End Property
```

UPDATE: I threw another gridview on the page and bound the data to it as well. It displays. So there must be something wrong with my Markup.

Here is the code for the bad one and the new one that works fine:

```
<div style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:50px;">

    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-lg-12 ">   
            <asp:GridView ID="grdParticipantList" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" DataKeyNames="ParticipantID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                HeaderStyle-BackColor="CornflowerBlue" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" CellPadding="4" Width="100%"    
                EmptyDataText="List of participants is currently empty." CssClass="table-hover">
                <Columns>   
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ParticipantID" HeaderText="ID" Visible="false" SortExpression="ID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" />   
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DeptPK" HeaderText="DeptPK" Visible="false" HeaderStyle-Width="0" ItemStyle-Width="0" SortExpression="DeptPK" />   
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DistrictCompanyName" HeaderText="District/Company" SortExpression="District" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" />   
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Firstname" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FName" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" />   
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Lastname" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LName" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" />   
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BusinessEmail" HeaderText="Business Email" SortExpression="EmailB" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" />   
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BusinessPhone" HeaderText="Business Phone" SortExpression="PhoneB" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" />   
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PersonalEmail" HeaderText="Personal Email" SortExpression="EmailP" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" />   
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PersonalCellPhone" HeaderText="Personal Phone" SortExpression="PhoneP" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" />   
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RetainContact" HeaderText="Retain Info" Visible="false" SortExpression="RC" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" />

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Retain Info" SortExpression="RC">
                        <ItemTemplate><%#IIf(Boolean.Parse(Eval("RetainContact").ToString()), "Yes", "No")%></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>   
            </asp:GridView>
```

```
    </div>


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Just a tip, nobody is really building post back pages likes this anymore and users don't like it. Have you considered using AJAX but JSON instead of XML? Web apps are JS these days and server calls are done through web services so there are no post backs.

Comment: You also might want to look at the ASP MVC paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this myself, because the problem went away.

I think it had something to do with markup further up the page.
Using bootstrap, and maybe a label should have been a span.

Anyway thanks to any who read and pondered this!